# How to get data from a website with GET request in Python app?

Tags: python, web-scraping, httprequest

I am trying to read the content of this website http://www.mex.cappna.biz/ using `GET` request in the following code.

```
for i in range(25200):

    time.sleep(1)

    with requests.Session() as s3:
               data3 = {"name":"chathub"}              
               r3 = s3.get('http://www.mex.cappna.biz/signalr/ping?_=1560840950921' , json = data3 ).json()
               print(r3)
```

But the result is :

> {'Response': 'pong'}

I used other links in the network section of google developers inside that website for my requests but didn't work. How can I read the contents of the tables in this page?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are after but 25200 get-requests seem like something incorrect to me. Furthermore in your request you are trying to jsonify the entire request. This is not needed, as `data3 = json.dumps({"name":"chathub"})` should be enough.

I think for your purposes you need a scraper tool of some kind, instead of this get request.

Comment: The reason for the `for` loop is it's an Online site and I want to read and plot online prices during the time.

Comment: Be that as it may, when you run the loop all the request will run as fast as they can get an answer with no break whatsoever. This means that if the server on the other side is really fast, this can be considered/mistaken for a DDOS attack.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the sleep line

Comment: BTW, I tried your code and got this error: `NameError: name 'json' is not defined`

Comment: I did, but program runs without any result!

Comment: I think I send my request to wrong link with wrong json abject, but don't know which link and what object as data I must send to the server?

Comment: I think you need to figure out that data for yourself. I don't know anything about the server you are talking to. A tip might be to check if they have an API available. That would really be a lot easier.